# yum install mongodb 3.2 fails

Tags: mongodb, centos, yum

I am trying to install mongodb 3.2 on a CentOS 7 machine and facing issues in locating the packages.

I have updated the repo file as per the documentation:

```
[mongodb-org-3.2]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When running `sudo yum install mongodb-org` I am getting this error:

```
[centos@ip-10-24-1-228 ~]$ sudo yum install mongodb-org
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.osuosl.org
 * epel: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * extras: mirror.lax.hugeserver.com
 * updates: mirror.hmc.edu
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Why do I get this message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out what was my problem. It was in my `yum.conf` file

```
exclude=mongodb-org,mongodb-org-server,mongodb-org-shell,mongodb-org-mongos,mongodb-org-tools
```

Once I commented out this line from `yum.conf`, everything went fine.

Comment: Stupid obvious - but my issue also

Answer (score 17):

You need to configure the package management system (`yum`).

Create a `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo` file to hold the following configuration information for the MongoDB repository:

If you have a 64bit system, use the following config:

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

32bit isn't recommended for production deployments, but you may use:

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/i686/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When you install the packages, you choose whether to install the current release or a previous one. This step provides the commands for both.

To install the latest stable version of MongoDB, run:

```
sudo yum install mongodb-org
```

To install a specific release of MongoDB, specify each component package individually and append to it the version number to the package name, as in the following example that installs the 3.2.0 release:

```
yum install mongodb-org-3.2.0 mongodb-org-server-3.2.0 mongodb-org-shell-3.2.0 mongodb-org-mongos-3.2.0 mongodb-org-tools-3.2.0
```

If you are still stuck, following [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/?_ga=1.169228258.273085478.1441642123) carefully might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have already done that. I have created the repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d and I am getting error message after every time followed in the documentation.

Comment: This saved my ass. The script on Mongodb.org does not work, but this one worked just file. Installed the 64 bit version using it

Answer (score 6):

You should know that this URL https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/ is not working anymore.

Go to http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/ and download mongodb-org.repo file.

Configure the package management system (`yum`), copy mongodb-org.repo to `/etc/yum.repos.d/`, so that you can install MongoDB directly, using `yum`.

Install the MongoDB packages and associated tools.

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org mongodb-org-server
```

Unfortunatelly mongodb website documentation suggests using https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/, but this is wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more recent version of [Idos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726003/7905714) answer from [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Red Hat Enterprise or CentOS Linux](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/).

#### Configure the package management system (yum).

Create a `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo` file so that you can install MongoDB directly, using `yum`.

**For MongoDB 3.6**

Use the following repository file:

```
[mongodb-org-3.6]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc
```

**For versions of MongoDB earlier than 3.6**

To install the packages from an earlier release series such as 3.4, you can specify the release series in the repository configuration. For example, to restrict your system to the 3.4 release series, create a `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo` file to hold the following configuration information for the MongoDB 3.4 repository:

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB 3.4 Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

You can find `.repo` files for each release in the repository itself. Remember that odd-numbered minor release versions (e.g. 3.5) are development versions and are unsuitable for production use.

#### Install the MongoDB packages.

To install the latest stable version of MongoDB, issue the following command:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

To install a specific release of MongoDB, specify each component package individually and append the version number to the package name, as in the following example:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-3.6.4 mongodb-org-server-3.6.4 mongodb-org-shell-3.6.4 mongodb-org-mongos-3.6.4 mongodb-org-tools-3.6.4
```

When you install the packages, you choose whether to install the current release or a previous one. This step provides the commands for both.

#### Start MongoDB.

You can start the mongod process by issuing the following command:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue is old and more than 2 years but I have received this error recently in **Mongo DB 4.0**

I have checked my yum.conf by

```
 vi /etc/yum.conf yum.conf
```

and there was one line with the following.

```
exclude=courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* **mongodb-org,mongodb-org-server,mongodb-org-shell,mongodb-org-mongos,mongodb-org-tools** mydns* nsd* p0f php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
```

Removed the

```
mod_ssl* mongodb-org,mongodb-org-server,mongodb-org-shell,mongodb-org-mongos,mongodb-org-tools
```

and changed it to

```
exclude=courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* nsd* p0f php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
```

This has fixed my issue and should fix yours.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Friend i will resoled problem

First Clean old data

```
sudo yum erase $(rpm -qa | grep mongod)
sudo rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/mongod*
sudo yum clean all
```

again create repo file new

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-enterprise-4.4.repo
```

file so that you can install MongoDB enterprise directly using yum:

```
[mongodb-enterprise-4.4]
name=MongoDB Enterprise Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.com/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-enterprise/4.4/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc
```

Install MongoDB Enterprise 4.4.
Issue the following command:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise
```

Install a specific release of MongoDB Enterprise.
To install a specific release, you must specify each component package individually along with the version number, as in the following example:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise-4.4.1 mongodb-enterprise-server-4.4.1 mongodb-enterprise-shell-4.4.1 mongodb-enterprise-mongos-4.4.1 mongodb-enterprise-tools-4.4.1
```

If you only install mongodb-enterprise=4.4.1 and do not include the component packages, the latest version of each MongoDB package will be installed regardless of what version you specified.

Pin a specific version of MongoDB Enterprise.
Although you can specify any available version of MongoDB Enterprise, yum upgrades the packages when a newer version becomes available. To prevent unintended upgrades, pin the package by adding the following exclude directive to your /etc/yum.conf file:

```
exclude=mongodb-enterprise,mongodb-enterprise-server,mongodb-enterprise-shell,mongodb-enterprise-mongos,mongodb-enterprise-tools
```

By default, MongoDB runs using the mongod user account and uses the following default directories:

```
/var/lib/mongo (the data directory)
/var/log/mongodb (the log directory)
```

➤ If you installed via the package manager,
The default directories are created, and the owner and group for these directories are set to mongod.

➤ If you installed by downloading the tarballs,
The default MongoDB directories are not created. To create the MongoDB data and log directories:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/mongo
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Any Error Come than ones Clean old

Option:- not create socket file than /tmp
in old socket file remove

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    
sudo systemctl start mongod

sudo service mongod status
```

more info to read [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/](http://more%20info%20to%20read%20https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/)

https://www.mysterydata.com/how-to-install-mongodb-4-0-on-centos-7-rhel-7/

Answer (score 0):

@nikolai.serdiuk seems to be correct. The baseurl provided in Mongo's Documentation doesn't seem to be functional. Replace that step with this instead (1):

yum-config-manager --add-repo http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/mongodb-org.repo

and then continue on with (2):

sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

Hope this helps.

Comment: yum-config-manager --add-repo http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/mongodb-org.repo   -->  Could not fetch/save url http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/mongodb-org.repo to file /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Create a mongodb-org.repo file 
    sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo

```
Add following content
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-
org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
Then execute sudo yum install mongodb-org
```

Reference:docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create repo in your redhat system.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo
```

and Enter `i`, and copy-past this.

```
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

and save it like- enter `ctrl + :` and enter `: + qw` 
and run this command

`yum install mongodb-org`

Answer (score 0):

Check and remove old version mongodb

```
yum list installed mongodb.x86_64
yum remove mongodb.x86_64
```

It helps

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend i will resoled problem

First Clean old data

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/mongod*
sudo yum clean all
```

again create repo file new

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-enterprise-4.4.repo
```

file so that you can install MongoDB enterprise directly using yum:

```
[mongodb-enterprise-4.4]
name=MongoDB Enterprise Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.com/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-enterprise/4.4/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc
```

Install MongoDB Enterprise 4.4.
Issue the following command:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise
```

Install a specific release of MongoDB Enterprise.
To install a specific release, you must specify each component package individually along with the version number, as in the following example:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise-4.4.1 mongodb-enterprise-server-4.4.1 mongodb-enterprise-shell-4.4.1 mongodb-enterprise-mongos-4.4.1 mongodb-enterprise-tools-4.4.1
```

If you only install mongodb-enterprise=4.4.1 and do not include the component packages, the latest version of each MongoDB package will be installed regardless of what version you specified.

Pin a specific version of MongoDB Enterprise.
Although you can specify any available version of MongoDB Enterprise, yum upgrades the packages when a newer version becomes available. To prevent unintended upgrades, pin the package by adding the following exclude directive to your /etc/yum.conf file:

```
exclude=mongodb-enterprise,mongodb-enterprise-server,mongodb-enterprise-shell,mongodb-enterprise-mongos,mongodb-enterprise-tools
```

By default, MongoDB runs using the mongod user account and uses the following default directories:

```
/var/lib/mongo (the data directory)
/var/log/mongodb (the log directory)
```

➤ If you installed via the package manager,
The default directories are created, and the owner and group for these directories are set to mongod.

➤ If you installed by downloading the tarballs,
The default MongoDB directories are not created. To create the MongoDB data and log directories:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/mongo
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Any Error Come than ones Clean old

Option:- not create socket file than /tmp
in old socket file remove

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    
sudo systemctl start mongod

sudo service mongod status
```

Answer (score -1):

This command

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/mongodb-org.repo
```

will create the `repo` as above suggested. Then it will work.

Comment: This does not currently work --- you'll get: https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/stable/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps to install MongoDB on CentOS

1. Add MongoDB yum repository

```
# vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo
```

2. Enter `i` and paste the below lines in the file

```
[MongoDB]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Press `esc` to save the vim file then enter `:wq` to quit the saved file.

3.Install MongoDB server

```
yum install mongodb-org
```

4. Start MongoDB Service

```
# systemctl start mongod.service    # For CentOS 7 
# service mongod restart            # For CentOS 6/5
```

5. Check Mongod version

```
mongod --version
```

Referance: [Installing MongoDB on CentOS](https://tecadmin.net/install-mongodb-on-centos/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24356550)

Comment: Thanks for the review. I have updated the answer and provided the necessary information.